Can't find python packages after "poetry install" in job Gitlab
I'm trying to use 'pytest' to run tests for job  in GitLab.
In the project I uses poetry, but after the command 'poetry install' does not see the installed libraries. Error:
pytest: command not found

My *-gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
  - testing

test_job:
  image: python:3.11-slim
  stage: testing
  script:
    - 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl jq && curl -sSL https://install.python- 
       poetry.org | python3'
    - 'PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/bin/"'
    - 'poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install'
    - 'pytest tests'

In Job everything need is installed, I check later 'poetry --version' / 'python --version', they are in place, but Python libraries (pytest) give errors.
My pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry]
name = "pytestwithtesting"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "educational project"
authors = ["avtest <3266@yandex.ru>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pytest = "^8.2.2"
pyhamcrest = "^2.1.0"
cards = "^2.0.0"
allure-pytest = "^2.13.5"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

And the project structure is small:
pytestwithtesting-|
                  |- /tests
                  |-.gitlab-ci.yml
                  |- REAMDE.md
                  |- poetry.toml
                  |- pyproject.toml

Please tell me what I might have missed?

Try python -m pytest

source .. activate worked for me
- pip install -q poetry
- python -m poetry install --no-interaction
- source `poetry env info --path`/bin/activate

